# Why do two different methods of computational submission of HTML5 forms return different behaviours?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, required

If I understand correctly, when HTML5 forms are computationally submitted via `.submit()` (rather than manually submitted by clicking `<input type="submit" />`) the browser will not check for form fields with `required` attributes.

But. If an existing `<input type="submit" />` is computationally clicked via `.click()`, then the form fields with `required` attributes ***are*** checked.

So... I hate to ask the obvious, but why the limitation on `.submit()` in the first place, if a computational `.click()` on an otherwise invisible `<input type="submit" />` checks for `required` anyway? What is the thinking here?

**Example:**

```js
var submitButtonForm = document.getElementsByClassName('submit-button-form')[0];
var submitButton = submitButtonForm.getElementsByClassName('submit-button')[0];

submitButton.addEventListener('click', function(){submitButtonForm.submit();}, false);
submitButtonForm.addEventListener('submit', function(){window.alert('Required attribute did not work and onsubmit event did not work either');}, false);

var clickButtonForm = document.getElementsByClassName('click-button-form')[0];
var clickButton = clickButtonForm.getElementsByClassName('click-button')[0];
var realSubmit = clickButtonForm.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');

clickButton.addEventListener('click', function(){realSubmit.click();}, false);
```

```css
form {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
width: 180px;
height: 180px;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 24px;
font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
background-color: rgb(227, 227, 255);
border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

label {
display: block;
margin-bottom: 24px;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 18px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

.click-button-form input[type="submit"] {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<form class="real-submit-form" action="#">
<h2>Form 1</h2>
<label>Required Field:
<input type="text" required />
</label>
<input type="submit" value="I am a real Submit" />
</form>

<form class="click-button-form" action="#">
<h2>Form 2</h2>
<label>Required Field:
<input type="text" required />
</label>
<input type="button" class="click-button" value="I am a Button [ .click() ]" />
<input type="submit" value="I am also a real Submit... (but hidden!)" />
</form>

<form class="submit-button-form" action="/">
<h2>Form 3</h2>
<label>Required Field:
<input type="text" required />
</label>
<input type="button" class="submit-button" value="I am a Button [ .submit() ]" />
</form>
```

Comment: I think this is largely opinion based since there is a lot of history about how javascript interacts with the DOM and not all of it can be rationally explained. To a large extent, features were included based on a particular implementation even though there were different behaviours in other implementations.

Comment: Yes, this is correct historically. You are right. But HTML5 was and is expressly intended to be a step forward from the muddle of the nineties and most of the noughties. The atttribute `required` is an HTML5 innovation.

Comment: @Rounin Have you considered filing an issue at DOM or HTML specifications? Or browser implementations? What is expected result?

Comment: Very good suggestion - and partly the intention behind my question above. Before I file an issue with mozilla etc., I'd like to check if I haven't missed something which everyone already knows about.

Comment: I look at it this way: When a user clicks the submit button, he/she requests a form submission, which you can in turn intercept, and demand the browser to perform some validation. On the other hand, if you call `.submit()` on a form from JS, you essentially demand the browser to perform the submission. In other words, it's about privileges of an end-user vs. you as the creator of the application, I think.

Comment: As far as that goes, I agree with you, @JeffreyWesterkamp. My point is that that the difference between "calling `.submit()` on a form from JS" and "calling `.click()` on a form's submit button from JS" is practically negligible. Either neither should pay attention to `require`, or, ideally, (to my mind) both should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From the comments**

I look at it this way: When a user clicks the submit button, he/she requests a form submission, which you can in turn intercept, and demand the browser to perform some validation. On the other hand, if you call `.submit()` on a form from JS, you essentially demand the browser to perform the submission. In other words, it's about privileges of an end-user vs. you as the creator of the application, I think.

> My point is that that the difference between "calling .submit() on a form from JS" and "calling .click() on a form's submit button from JS" is practically negligible.

Well, actually it isn't. A computed `click()` and an actual click on the button both have identical effect: a click event is being dispatched. That is the responsibility of the click method: it should 'pretend' the user clicked the button. It's *not* the responsibility of the `click()` method to figure out what you *intend* to do through that click event. It just *'clicks the button'* for you.

The same goes for the `submit()` method: it's not its responsibility to figure out whether you *intend* to actually proceed with submission, or actually want to perform some validation first. It just does its job: proceeding with form submission.

**The difference in effect might be small in some cases, but difference in semantics is significant.**

You're actually left with a choice - some control over what should happen - of how you want to proceed with the submission. If you're not certain the input can be trusted, just call the `click()` method, otherwise call the `submit()` method.

> Either neither should pay attention to require, or, ideally, (to my mind) both should.

When you call `submit()` on a form programmatically I think it's fair that the engine may assume you are sure you want to proceed with the for submission. That's what the method is designed for.

It's probable that the absence of a validation procedure on `submit()` is intentional. It gives us the freedom to shape our own procedures and rules for our applications. For example, one might want to periodically save a *draft* of user input, regardless of whether that input is valid. Error messages can then notify the user about the invalid input. This is very convenient for large forms (blogposts, vacancies, you name it), that take some time to fill out.

If you're not sure whether you can trust the current input, you'd want to translate this pseudo code to a working version:

```
if (isValid(myForm)) {
    myForm.submit()
} else {
    // Some function that checks the validity of all inputs, and
    // displays messages accordingly.
    showValidationErrors(myForm)
}
```

When a click event is dispatched (and thus is assumed to be triggered by a 'non-trusted' source), the browsers validation facilities automatically kick in, I think that's fair as well.

Comment: Excellent answer, @JeffreyWestercamp - really well thought out. I like your distinction between a) a computational simulation of a user click and b) a request to the browser to submit the current form, whether it validates or not. I will look at these methods in future as a *request to submit* and a *demand to submit*.